# Why do Androids in Dragon Ball Z sometimes use cars?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

There are a few Dragon Ball Z scenes in which Androids 16, 17 and 18 ride a truck despite the fact that they are capable of flight. It grants extra time to the heroes to recover (such as in Goku's case) and think about or prepare for what to do next, like exploring Cell's egg, or merging Picollo with Kami. To me, it seems both unreasonable and humorous at the same time.

Nevertheless, I don't understand the reason for why the producers/storywriters decided to do this. Is there any reason given for this strange choice? Could it be some kind of plot hole or plot device?

Answer (score 14):

There was a specific reason why they were using the car:

17 and 18 weren't that emotionally invested in killing Goku, and they were just  killing time.

They knew that taking a car was impractical, but they took one anyway because android 17 felt like it

[image]

Comment: Yep! That is the correct answer.